# Levi-Civita Connection with Geodesic Spray Containing Flow Lines of Time-Independent Vector Field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, classical-mechanics

Let $Q^n$ be a closed manifold and $M = TQ$ be its tangent bundle.

In [1], it is worked out in Equation 5.31 that there is a kinetic energy Riemannian metric $g$ on $Q$ with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla_g$ such that for any potential function $V$ and time-dependent forcing vector field $F$, the equation of motion is ${\nabla_g}_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} = -\text{grad}V + F$. This can be extended to include a Raleigh dissipative forces function $R$ and equation of motion ${\nabla_g}_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} = -\text{grad}_qV + \text{grad}_{\dot{q}}R + F$. In the absence of a time-dependent forcing vector field $F$, this becomes ${\nabla_g}_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} = -\text{grad}_qV + \text{grad}_{\dot{q}}R$. EDIT: Note that when $V = R = 0$ and $F = 0$, the equation of motion becomes ${\nabla_g}_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} = 0$, and the system simply follows its "kinetic energy geodesics".

My question is, is it worked out anywhere that if one has a time-independent, complete vector field $\xi$ on $M$, there is a Levi-Civita connection $\nabla_{\xi}$ on $M$ with the flow lines $\Phi_t$ of $\xi$ being geodesics of $\nabla_{\xi}$?

This seems a natural generalization of the ideas of [1], but I'm unable to find a reference. I can likely work it out myself if necessary, but I'm hoping it's already done so I won't have to "re-invent the wheel".

<sub>[1] *Bullo, Francesco; Lewis, Andrew D.*, Geometric control of mechanical systems. Modeling, analysis, and design for simple mechanical control systems., Texts in Applied Mathematics 49. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 0-387-22195-6/hbk). xxiv, 726 p. (2005). [ZBL1066.70002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1066.70002).</sub>

Comment: I upvoted the question as it's interesting, though the motivation paragraph is not completely clear to me. What do you mean by the equations of motion associated to $(g,F,V)$? For $V=0$, I though to the Euler-Lagrange equations for the Lagrangian $\frac 1 2 \|\cdot\|_g^2 + V $ but then the result would be trivial.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain Yes, if V=0, then this case is covered in [1], and the geodesics are the flow lines. My question is for V (and possibly R) not zero.

Comment: The book is 700 pages long, can you give us a more precise reference? What theorem is in the book? 

On the other hand, if I understood correctly I am a bit puzzled about the motivation paragraph. You say there exists a metric such that...But that the Euler-Lagrange equation for the Lagrangian $\mathcal L_{g,V}=\frac 1 2 \| \cdot\|_g^2 + V$ are given by the Newton equation $\nabla^g_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma = -\nabla V$ is true for any metric.

Comment: Done; it's Equation 5.31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated the answer is negative: the velocity of geodesics has constant length, but an integral curve for a general vector field does not have to.

The question becomes interesting if you formulate it by asking that the support of the curve is the support of a geodesic. But even in this case the answer is negative.
Indeed, consider a vector field over a compact manifold,  vanishing at some points $p_-$ and $p_+$, $p_-\neq p_+$, and suppose that there is a flowline $\gamma$ limiting to $p_-$ and $p_+$ at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ respectively.
The support of $\gamma$ cannot be the support of a geodesic, as a geodesic on a compact manifold is a curve that has either infinite length or is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^1$.

Comment: Perfect! My dissertation advisor says sometimes, you just need a pair of fresh eyes to look at the problem, but I suspect in this case, it's deeper. I am familiar with all the concepts in your answer, and stared at the problem for weeks, and didn't come up with your analysis. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I think that maybe sharpening the hypothesis you can get something. For example, there are results of this kind if the vector field is the  gradient of a bounded function, then one can consider a Jacobi metric (which essentially is a conformal change of the metric) and then the geodesics for that metric will be flowlines up to reparametrization provided that the  flowlines is of energy $e=1/2K+V$ larger than $\sup \mathrm{Im}(V)$.
This is Theorem 3.7.7 (pg 228) in Abraham & Marsden's Foundations of Mechanics (2nd edition).